# Laravel update database table design

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

I have a php laravel projekt where I need to add a field to one/more models (Eloquent). I don't have much experience in php and never tried laravel before.

The class looks like this now

```
class Player extends Eloquent
{
use GenderTrait;
use VisibilityTrait;
use PlayerPhotoTrait;
use PlayerActionTrait;

const GENDER_MALE = 2;
const GENDER_FEMALE = 1;

/**
 * The database table used by model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'players';

/**
 * Parameters for `actions` relation.
 *
 * @see PlayerActionTrait::actions()
 * @var array
 */
protected $actionModel = [
    'name' => 'PlayerAction',
    'foreignKey' => 'player_id',
];

/**
 * The list of mass-assignable attributes.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'start_value',
    'gender',
    'is_visible',
    'nation',
];

/**
 * The list of validation rules.
 *
 * @var array
 */
public static $rules = [
    'name' => 'required',
    'nation' => 'required|numeric',
    'start_value' => 'required|numeric',
];

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

}

/**
 * Players country.
 *
 * @return Country
 */
public function country()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Country', 'nation');
}

/**
 * Player videos.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function videos()
{
    return $this->morphMany('YoutubeLink', 'owner');
}
}
```

I would like to add a string field called "level" but I have no idea how to go about it. If I create the field in MySQL first and then the models get updated, if I update the models and then Laravel update MySQL for me?

Im looking forward to hearing what I can do :)

Comment: Are you using migrations? If not I strongly suggest you do so https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations

Comment: A useful link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791613/add-new-column-migrate-to-database

Comment: Yes, the project is using migrations but I've only just now taken over the project from someone else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add migration:

```
php artisan make:migration add_fields_to_players_table --table=players
```

Open in `/database/migrations` new migration and write

```
Schema::table('players', function ($table) {
    $table->string('new_string_field');
});
```

Now you need to run migrations

```
php artisan migrate
```

More info and available column types [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations)

Comment: Do you know if this is possible on a one.com server?

Comment: one.com provides ssh access, so you able to run commands on your server

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll try it when I get the chance. Will my Players table + model get updated automatically after I run the last command?

Comment: Table will be update and new field will be accessible

Comment: So after I run the command I need to add the new field in the "fillable" array and then I can access it in my controllers?

Comment: When I try to call `php artisan make:migration`
I get an error
`[InvalidArgumentException]
There are no commands defined in the "make" namespace.`

EDIT: I tried to use `php artisan migrate:make` as it is larval 3 the project is running