# How can i add an extra column to an existing table which has data without losing it

Tags: laravel, migration, database-migration, laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel 5.5 and i would like to add an extra column to an existing table called `users`.

The problem is that `php artisan migrate` doesn't add the extra column.

1) Is it possible since table is not empty?

2) Why the below code block doesn't work?

By running `php artisan make:migration update_users_column --table=users` a file is created :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class UpdateUsersColumn extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->boolean('email_sent_to_user', true);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
//        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
//            //
//        });
    }
}
```

After running `php artisan migrate` the `migrations` table is updated but `users` table is not updated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791613/add-a-new-column-to-existing-table-in-a-migration

Comment: @JunaidMasood I have already searched and seen other posts. I can't understand why the above code doesn't work this is why i posted the question.

Comment: do you have this migration in migrations table ?

Answer (score 1):

The code block is working alright. The problem was with the procedure of transfering files from my local computer to the server(not correct permissions so the file was not actually uploaded after my edits).