# How to add new column name in existing migration in laravel5.5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.5

I have already created a migration file and tables have been created in database.
Now, i want to add new column to the existing migration file.
What I am doing is, I opened the migration file and added column names in up() function, after adding them, then i run command

```
php artisan migrate
```

The new columns did'nt get generated, instead i received an error.
[image]

How can I add new columns to existing table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a new column to existing table in a migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791613/add-a-new-column-to-existing-table-in-a-migration)

Comment: You don't modify migration files that have already been run; you create a new migration file purely to add the new column

Comment: Okay! and for this first i'll have to delete that particular migration file and how?

Comment: Roll your version control back to the previous version of that migration file

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new migration like below;

```
php artisan make:migration add_new_column_to_xtable_table --table="xtable"
```

then open your migraiton and add your new column here.

Then type "`php artisan migrate`" on console