# How to add a column after another column in sqlite using Laravel migrations?

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel-5.4

Is there a method in Laravel 5.4 to add a column after/before another column inside a sqlite table? Like `after('column')` for MySql?

Why I'm in a hurry is because whenever I tried to rename a column using Laravel migration, it jumps and stick to the last / end of a table!

Is there a way to get rid out of this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791613/add-a-new-column-to-existing-table-in-a-migration

Comment: This doesn't work for sqlite ☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.

However there is apparently a workaround:

[Insert new column into table in sqlite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253804/insert-new-column-into-table-in-sqlite/4253879#4253879)

Disclaimer: I rarely use sqlite and cannot verify this works. Good luck.