# How to just update a table and add new line with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, database-migration

in the database table as below;

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('current_adresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('current_name',50)->nullable();
            $table->string('current_surname',50)->nullable();
            $table->string('telephone',25)->nullable();
          $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

I want to do as below;

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('current_adresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('current_name',50)->nullable();
            $table->string('current_surname',50)->nullable();
            $table->string('gsm',25)->nullable();
            $table->string('telephone',25)->nullable();
          $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

how can I update the new column(gsm column) without refreshing(php artisan migrate:refresh)

Comment: Use models in your controller

Comment: I did not understand :(

Comment: New line or new column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `new` migration-

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('current_adresses', function($table) {
        $table->string('gsm',25)->nullable();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('current_adresses', function($table) {
        $table->dropColumn('gsm');
   });
}
```

See t[his](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791613/add-a-new-column-to-existing-table-in-a-migration) link for better understanding.

Comment: Thank you bro. Exactly as I want :)

Comment: @ufuk accept this answer, by doing so it may help others too