# How to add new column to existing table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am adding new column name title in my table tasks. But I am getting an error that this column does not exist in that table. Can anybody help me to resolve that error. Here is my code:

`php artisan make:migration add_title_to_tasks_table --table="tasks"` and then added this code

```
Schema::table('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) { 
  $table->string('title');
});
```

to new table file created

Comment: Are you using migrations? Check - https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations

Comment: yes i used php artisan make:migration add_title_to_tasks_table --table="tasks"

Comment: You need to alter the table and add the new columns. Then migrate again.

Comment: how to alter table and add new columns

Comment: You'd need to make a new migration to reflect the changes you want to make. Then run `php artisan migrate` to "push" the changes to you database.

Comment: can you please share your create table and alter table migration code

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#creating-columns

Comment: php artisan make:migration add_title_to_tasks_table --table="tasks" and then added Schema::table('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->string('title');
        }); to that new table file created

Comment: update it in question

Comment: I just updated code in questioin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791613/add-a-new-column-to-existing-table-in-a-migration   check this link you will find the answer for your question.

Answer (score 4):

To Alter table and add column.

```
     /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up() {
        Schema::table('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->string('title')->after('id');

           // to change column datatype or change it to `nullable` 
           // or set default values , this is just example

           $table->string('title')->default('Test')->change(); 

        });
    }
```

You can refere documentation here, [Laravel Migration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#creating-columns)

Comment: getting this error: "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 table tasks has no column named title (SQL: insert into "tasks" ("title", "description", "user_id", "updated_at", "created_at" ▶"

Comment: is your migration run successfully ? match table structure with your requirement.

Comment: In order to modify an existing column, there is a dependency that one has to install.. `Doctrine/DBAL` https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#modifying-columns

Comment: i installed dependency but still same issue

Comment: @NishaSharma, if your comment is related to my answer/post, please add your comment there.. It is bit confusing for me to recognize as to whether you are referring to my post or Mayank's post

Comment: @SaiyanPrince i tried migartion php artisan make:migration add_title_to_tasks_table --table="tasks" and then added your code to that file and run php artisan migrate but getting error that tasks table already exists

Comment: Can anyone help me

Comment: I know this will work. But i need alternate solution on already installed files

Answer (score 3):

For those who are new to laravel and looking for a solution, please follow the steps
1). `php artisan make:migration add_title_to_tasks_table --table="tasks"`

2). Edit the newly created file in the migrations folder and add the below.

```
public function up() {
    Schema::table('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->string('title')->after('id');

       // to change column datatype or change it to `nullable` 
       // or set default values , this is just example

       $table->string('title')->default('Test')->change(); 

    });
}
```

3). Run the migrations command.

php artisan migrate

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->string('title')->after('your-column-name');
    });
}
```

Replace 'your-column-name' with your existing column name.

Save the file. From terminal, execute:

```
php artisan migrate
```

The above command will add the column to your table.

You are getting that error because you are not running the `migrate` command.
Whenever you create a migration file, you must execute the above command in order to see the changes in your database table.

Also, if the new column does not exist in the models `$fillable` property, you will have to add it there as well..

```
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @return  array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'title', // <-- new column name
    // .. other column names
];
```

Failing to do update the `$fillable` property will result in `MassAssignmentExecption`

Hope this helps you out. Happy Coding. Cheers.