# How to add column to existing table in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm new to laravel framework. For making a blog URL's to SEO friendly, I need to add an extra column to the existing blog tables for the laravel website. Can we directly add a column to a table directly in the database or not? Can we add a column without commands or migrations? Would you please suggest an easy method to add the column?

Comment: you can use migration as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16791988/4648586), or add it directly using the dbms. may we know what dbms you are using?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. we are using mysql

Comment: if you are using raw mysql without laravel migrations, you can use [`ALTER TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) query, something like `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN "my-new-column" varchar(MAX)` or something...

Comment: Best solution is to use a framework the way they intent you to use it. I would strongly suggest using laravel's migrations.

Answer (score 3):

Add migration

```
php artisan make:migration add_fieldname_to_tablename
```

Code methods migration

```
public function up()
{
        Schema::table('tablename', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->datatype('column_name')->nullable();
        });
}    

public function down()
{
        Schema::table('tablename', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('column_name');
        });
}
```

Run migration

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

Better is to add at migration level but if you want to directly add at DB level that is also an option. **But update migration as well so that it will have all the columns.**

Comment: but the best practice is to create migration file for add or create or update column in database in laravel