# Laravel 8 - Change existing migration

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing on `Laravel Framework 8.33.1` and have the following migration on my local environment and also in production.

```
class CreateCompanyTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('company', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('company_id');
            $table->integer('messageId');
            $table->string('url');
            $table->timestamps();

            /**
            New table:
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('company_id')->nullable($value = true);
            $table->integer('messageId');
            $table->integer('people_id')->nullable($value = true);
            $table->string('url')->nullable($value = true);
            $table->timestamps();
             */
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('company');
    }
}
```

I would like to change the migration with the following adapted fields:

```
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('company_id')->nullable($value = true);
            $table->integer('messageId');
            $table->integer('people_id')->nullable($value = true);
            $table->string('url')->nullable($value = true);
            $table->timestamps();
```

As I am using the current migration in production I do not want to lose data.

I simply tried to modify the migration file with my new table definition, but I get:

```
> php artisan migrate
Nothing to migrate.
```

Any suggestions how to change the migration properly in laravel?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: If company table gets dropped, is it ok?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791613/add-a-new-column-to-existing-table-in-a-migration This almost has everything you need.

Answer (score 2):

To modify an existing table, create a new migration.

`php artisan make:migration alter_company_table`

```php
class AlterCompanyTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('company', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('company_id')->nullable()->change();
            $table->integer('people_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('url')->nullable()->change();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('company', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('company_id')->nullable(false)->change();
            $table->dropColumn('people_id');
            $table->string('url')->nullable(false)->change();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind losing data and you are in development mode, you can do `php artisan migrate:rollback` and after execute: `php artisan migrate`. So your migrations works correctly. You can to read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#rolling-back-migrations).

Now, if you just want to add new tables and modify others in you database, you should make another migration. But before this, you should to install [doctrine/dbal](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#modifying-columns) to be able to modify your tables correctly, or else, it will give you many errors. After, add this lines in your `config/database.php`

```
use Illuminate\Database\DBAL\TimestampType;

'dbal' => [
    'types' => [
        'timestamp' => TimestampType::class,
    ],
],
```

Now you can do: `php artisan make:migration add_new_tables_to_company` and your file in `database/migrations`.

```
class AlterCompanyTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('company', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('company_id')->nullable()->change();
            $table->integer('people_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('url')->nullable()->change();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('company', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('company_id')->nullable(false)->change();
            $table->dropColumn('people_id');
            $table->string('url')->nullable(false)->change();
        });
    }
}
```